# How can I use the Solve command to find an eigenvector corresponding to a specific eigenvalue?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have the following matrix in Mathematica:

```
L={{0, 0, (111/190), (79/190)},
  {0.16, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0.12, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0.19, 0}}
```

Then using `Eigenvalues[Transpose[L]]`, I'm able to get the eigenvalues of the transpose of `L`.

But I'm having a difficult time trying to solve for the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue, 0.257651, using the solve command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an accurate estimate of an eigenvalue, you can find the corresponding eigenvector with `NullSpace`

```
NullSpace[L - (0.25765082710282156` + 0.` I) IdentityMatrix[4]]
(* {{0.812504 + 0. I, 0.504561 + 0. I, 0.234998 + 0. I, 0.173295 + 0. I}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

`Eigensystem` gives you eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, no need for `Solve`:

```
Eigensystem[Transpose[L]]

{{0.257651, -0.0698441 + 0.212197 I, -0.0698441 - 0.212197 I, -0.117963}, 
 {{-0.234715 + 0. I, -0.377966 + 0. I, -0.811528 + 0. I, -0.378777 + 0. I}, 
  {-0.221686 + 0.163666 I, -0.120288 - 0.365452 I, 0.716245 + 0. I, 0.418347 + 0.296685 I}, 
  {-0.221686 - 0.163666 I, -0.120288 + 0.365452 I, 0.716245 + 0. I, 0.418347 - 0.296685 I}, 
  {-0.262679 + 0. I, 0.193664 + 0. I, -0.190376 + 0. I, 0.925879 + 0. I}}}
```

Comment: Since I'm solving for a left eigenvector, would I have to take the transpose of {-0.234715 + 0. I, -0.377966 + 0. I, -0.811528 + 0. I, -0.378777 + 0. I}, for example?

Comment: No, the vectors in the second list are the left eigenvectors. Just try it out if you're unsure. And do read the documentation please.

Comment: The documentation on the Wolfram site?