# Plot a list vertically in a graph

Tags: plotting

For a parametrized matrix $H(\lambda)$, how do I plot all the eigenvalues of the matrix vertically corresponding to a particular value of $\lambda$? i.e. we use $\lambda$ as the horizontal axis and the eigenvalues are along the vertically axis.

ps. We can for sure plot each of these points separately, but I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a MWE of the input?

Comment: what does MWE stand for?

Comment: MWE is a minimum working example that somewhat represents your problem. Having that makes it much easier for people to help you as they don’t have to spend so much time writing code or guessing what you want. In this case, even providing a small sample dataset would be really helpful.

Comment: [Tracking Eigenvalues Through a Crossing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165167/tracking-eigenvalues-through-a-crossing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works for you (I made up a matrix that depends on lambda since none was provided):

```
ClearAll[m] 
m[lambda_] := {{1 + lambda,       2 lambda,          3}, 
               {3 + lambda^2,   1 - lambda,          2}, 
               {2,                      -1,   3 lambda}}

DiscretePlot[Evaluate@Eigenvalues@m[l], {l, 1, 10}, Filling -> None]
```

[image: plot for discrete values of lambda]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Eigenvalues@m[l], {l, 1, 10}]
```

[image: plot for continuous values of lambda]