# Improving a plot of eigenvalues versus a parameter obtained by ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

I have a bunch of $m \times m$ matrices with $m\geq 2$, which I would like to plot their eigenvalues as a function of a parameter. These eigenvalues are usually complex and wind together as a function of the parameter.

Here is an example to demonstrate the idea. A $2 \times 2$ Hamiltonian reads

```
A[x_] := {{1.2 I + 0.012 Cos[x] + 0.63 Cos[2 x] + 0.3 I Sin[2 x], 0.645}, {0.645, 0}}
```

I have plotted the real and imaginary parts of eigenvalues as a function of $x$ using

```
r1 = Table[{Re[Sort[Eigenvalues[A[x]]][[1]]], 
    Im[Sort[Eigenvalues[A[x]]][[1]]], x}, {x, 0.0, 7, 0.1}];
r2 = Table[{Re[Sort[Eigenvalues[A[x]]][[2]]], 
    Im[Sort[Eigenvalues[A[x]]][[2]]], x}, {x, 0.0, 7, 0.1}];

g1 = ListPointPlot3D[r1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
g2 = ListPointPlot3D[r2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red]];

Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 3, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 150]
```

The output is this image[image]

I would like to ensure that each strand is only one color; currently, due to the `Sort`, they have mixed colors. If possible, I would also like to have these strands as tubes instead of points. It would be great if I could get the projection of these strands on the $(\Re[\lambda], \Im[\lambda])$ plane. I prefer not to use any analytical forms of eigenvalues, as attaining analytical eigenvalues is challenging for matrices with high ranks. Do you have suggestions for improving such plots?

Comment: ListLinePlot3D?

Comment: Line plots won't do the job because of the mixing of eigenvalue order.

Comment: Maybe some of the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165167/) could help?

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisK, for sharing the link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

A[x_] = {{1.2  I + 0.012  Cos[x] + 0.63  Cos[2  x] + 0.3  I  Sin[2  x], 
      0.645}, {0.645, 0}} // Rationalize // Simplify;

ev[x_] = Eigenvalues[A[x]] // Simplify;

ReImPlot[Evaluate@ev[x], {x, 0, 7},
 PlotLegends -> {"ev1", "ev2"}]
```

[image]

For 3D use [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[
  Flatten[{ReIm[#], x}] & /@ ev[x]],
 {x, 0, 7},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Re, Im, x}),
 PlotLegends -> {"ev1", "ev2"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To color each strand separately

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[Flatten[{ReIm[#], x}] & /@ ev[x]],
   {x, 0, 7}];
```

Extract all of the data points from the `ParametricPlot3D`

```
data = Join @@ Cases[pp, Line[pts_] :> pts, All];
```

Find the shortest tour and split into two segments

```
data2 = Split[Most@data[[FindShortestTour[data][[2]]]],
   Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.4 &];

ListLinePlot3D[data2,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Re, Im, x}),
 PlotLegends -> {"ev1", "ev2"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** 2D projection of strands

```
data3 = data2 /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y, -1};

ListLinePlot3D[Join[data2, data3], 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Re, Im, x}),
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"ev1", "ev2"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3/4},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want each strand to appear in one color. Currently, it is a mix of both colors.

Comment: See edit for update

Comment: (+1)This is great. Thank you very much. Could you also add a 2d projection of these strands on the Re-Im plane? This way all questions of my thread are addressed by your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with sorting eigenvalues and eigenvectors. "Eigenvalues" sorts numerical eigenvalues according to their real parts. Therefore if we have eigenvalues that crosses for some value of the parameter, the eigenvalues do not change smoothly. Rather, what was the first eigenvalue before the crossing, becomes the second one. We can see this by:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[Eigenvalues[A[x]]]], {x, 0, 7}]
Plot[Evaluate[Im@Eigenvalues[A[x]]], {x, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is the issue, and for the same reason, LinePlots mix everything, and I cannot use them to greater my 3d figure.

Comment: There is no simple solution to this, but you may draw your plot piecewise.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I see. Is it possible that I keep both strands in one color but somehow add a direction of flow to the projection on the plane?

Comment: You may add an arrow by `g3=Graphics3D[Arrow[{pt1,pt2}]]` to the "Show"