# Assign the result to the lists

Tags: interpolation

I am following the solution of the mixing eigenvalues from [Carl Woll's answer in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195770/92514). In the end, the eigenvalues are plotted using this formula

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Indexed[sol[x], i], {i, 6}], {x, -.1, .1}]
```

It plots the six eigenvalues. My question is how to assign each eigenvalue to a separate table.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign each eigenvalue to a separate table"? Please clarify. Anyway, if I have to guess: do you think the output of `NDSolveValue` is something like a `List`? If so, you're wrong. The output of `NDSolveValue` is a `InterpolatingFunction[…]`, please observe the output of `NDSolveValue` carefully and check the document accordingly.

Comment: @xzczd, ok, I see, that it returns an interpolating function. My problem is that I want to do another calculation on these eigenvalues. So, is it possible to assign each eigenvalue, separately, to its interpolated function?

For example, to define `f[x_]:=`, which will plot only, let's say, the green curve in the example.